# ES6 'import' causing error with Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to make a Poker game using JavaScript es6, but even with babel, when the game is run, the following error is thrown:

> Unexpected reserved word `{ import Hand from './hand';`

I have the following in my node_modules:

- `babel`
- `babel-core`
- `babel-loader`
- `babel-preset-es2015`

webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./player.js",
  output: {
    path: "./bundle",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: [/\.jsx?$/, /\.js?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", '.jsx']
  }
};
```

I am trying to simply run player.js to test the constructor:

```
import Hand from './hand';

export default class Player {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hand = dealHand();
  }

  dealHand() {
    Hand.deal();
  }

}

let me = new Player("sam");
console.log(`my name is ${me.name}`)
console.log(me.hand);
```

Comment: How are you transpiling with babel? Are you using webpack? Sounds like somewhere its not actually picking up the transpiled version

Comment: It's not enough to just install these modules—you have to add the presets you use to the `.babelrc` file.

Comment: run this:   node -r babel-register player.js

Comment: @finalfreq Yes, I added the config file above.

Comment: It'd be worthwhile to `npm i --save-dev babel-cli` then do `node_modules/.bin/babel player.js` to see what the output looks like.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the full error message including stack trace please?